Tool stops working after death, but only in the Roblox Client, not Roblox Studio
In the experience I'm currently working on there has been a bug where, after death, the gun tools would stop working unless dropped and picked back up. However, when trying to debug this, I found that the bug only appeared in the Roblox Player and not Roblox Studio.
I've tried a couple of things so far, such as removing the tools from the player upon death and preventing them from shooting while dead. However, this does not seem to fix the issue. From a previous bug, I think it may have to do with the multiple local variables being defined at the beginning of the LocalScript? Before, the guns would break before the line local muzzleFlash.Enabled = false as they would appear on the gun (I've since disabled the effect without the use of the script, but it remains there as a safety precaution)
The strangest part is that it only effects two out of the four current weapons. The shotgun and SMG consistently break, while the pistol and minigun haven't broken so far? This confuses me even more since I use the same basis for all of my guns.
How am I supposed to debug my code when it's only broken in one client? Has anyone else run into this issue?
My Code Below:
**-- This is the "pistolLocalScript" that controls my Pistol tool**

local userInputService = game:getService("UserInputService")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local tool = script.Parent
local debounce = false
local playerDead = false
local pistolShootAnim = tool.Animations:WaitForChild("pistolShootAnim")
local pistolShootAnimTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(pistolShootAnim)
local muzzleFlash = tool.Handle.Barrel.ParticleEmitter
local muzzleLight = tool.Handle.Barrel.PointLight
muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
muzzleLight.Enabled = false

local pistolAmmo = 8
local maxPistolAmmo = 8
local reloading = false

humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    playerDead = true
    tool:Destroy()
end)

-- Reload Function
local function reload()
    if reloading == false then
        reloading = true
        tool.Sounds["Gun Reload"]:play()
        task.wait(1)
        pistolAmmo = maxPistolAmmo
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..pistolAmmo.."/"..maxPistolAmmo..""
        reloading = false
    end
end

-- Shooting Function
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    if playerDead ~= true and debounce == false and pistolAmmo > 0 and reloading == false then
        debounce = true
        pistolAmmo -= 1
        tool.Shoot:FireServer(mouse.Hit.Position) -- Perhaps something happens before here? Gunshot noises are played server-side after this remoteEvent is detected.
        muzzleFlash.Enabled = true
        muzzleLight.Enabled = true
        pistolShootAnimTrack:Play()
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..pistolAmmo.."/"..maxPistolAmmo..""
        print(pistolAmmo)
        task.wait(0.2)
        muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
        muzzleLight.Enabled = false
        debounce = false
    elseif pistolAmmo <= 0 and reloading == false then
        reload()
    end
end)

-- User Input Reload
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(inputObject, isTyping)
    if isTyping then return end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R and pistolAmmo < maxPistolAmmo then
        reload()
    end
end)

-- Equip Function
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Equip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = true
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..pistolAmmo.."/"..maxPistolAmmo..""
    print("equipped!")
    reloading = false
    muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
    muzzleLight.Enabled = false
end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Unequip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = false
    reloading = true
    muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
    muzzleLight.Enabled = false
end)

**-- This is the "smgLocalScript" that controls my SMG tool**

local userInputService = game:getService("UserInputService")
local runService = game:GetService(("RunService"))
local debris = game:GetService("Debris")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local tool = script.Parent
local debounce = false
local playerDead = false
local equipCheck = false
local smgShootAnim = tool.Animations:WaitForChild("smgShootAnim")
local smgShootAnimTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(smgShootAnim)
local muzzleFlash = tool.Handle.Barrel.ParticleEmitter
local muzzleLight = tool.Handle.Barrel.PointLight
muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
muzzleLight.Enabled = false
tool.Handle.Magazine.Transparency = 0

local smgAmmo = 24
local maxsmgAmmo = 24
local reloading = false

local holding = false
local lastShot = 0
local shotDelay = 0.05

humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    playerDead = true
    tool:Destroy()
end)

-- Reload Function
local function reload()
    if reloading == false then
        reloading = true
        local fakeMag = tool.Handle.Magazine:clone()
        fakeMag.Parent = game.Workspace
        tool.Handle.Magazine.Transparency = 1
        fakeMag.WeldConstraint:Destroy()
        fakeMag.CanCollide = true
        debris:AddItem(fakeMag, 5)
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = "Wait..."
        tool.Sounds["SMG Reload"]:play()
        task.wait(3)
        tool.Handle.Magazine.Transparency = 0
        smgAmmo = maxsmgAmmo
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..smgAmmo.."/"..maxsmgAmmo..""
        reloading = false
    end
end

-- Shooting Function
local function shoot()
    local time = tick()
    if time - lastShot >= shotDelay then
        lastShot = time
        if playerDead ~= true and debounce == false and smgAmmo > 0 and reloading == false then
            debounce = true
            smgAmmo -= 1
            tool.Shoot:FireServer(mouse.Hit.Position)
            muzzleFlash.Enabled = true
            muzzleLight.Enabled = true
            smgShootAnimTrack:Play()
            player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..smgAmmo.."/"..maxsmgAmmo..""
            print(smgAmmo)
            task.wait(0.05)
            muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
            muzzleLight.Enabled = false
            debounce = false
        elseif smgAmmo <= 0 and reloading == false then
            reload()
        end
    end
end

tool.Activated:Connect(shoot)

-- User Input Reload
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(inputObject, isTyping)
    if isTyping then return end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R and smgAmmo < maxsmgAmmo then
        reload()
    elseif inputObject.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and equipCheck == true then
        holding = true
        print(holding)
    end
end)

userInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if gameProcessedEvent then return end
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        holding = false
        print(holding)
    end
end)

runService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if holding == true then
        shoot()
        print(holding)
    end
end)

-- Equip Function
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Equip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = true
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..smgAmmo.."/"..maxsmgAmmo..""
    print("equipped!")
    reloading = false
    equipCheck = true
end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Unequip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = false
    reloading = true
    holding = false
    equipCheck = false
end)

**-- This is the "shotgunLocalScript" that controls my shotgun tool**

local userInputService = game:getService("UserInputService")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local tool = script.Parent
local debounce = false
local playerDead = false
local shotgunShootAnim = tool.Animations:WaitForChild("shotgunShootAnim")
local shotgunShootAnimTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(shotgunShootAnim)
local muzzleFlash = tool.Handle.Barrel.ParticleEmitter
local muzzleLight = tool.Handle.Barrel.PointLight
muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
muzzleLight.Enabled = false

local shotgunAmmo = 4
local maxshotgunAmmo = 4
local reloading = false

humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    playerDead = true
    tool:Destroy()
end)

-- Reload Function
local function reload()
    if reloading == false then
        reloading = true
        repeat
            shotgunAmmo = shotgunAmmo + 1
            tool.Sounds["Shotgun Reload"]:play()
            player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..shotgunAmmo.."/"..maxshotgunAmmo..""
            task.wait(0.75)
        until shotgunAmmo == maxshotgunAmmo
        reloading = false
    end
end

-- Shooting Function
tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    if playerDead ~= true and debounce == false and shotgunAmmo > 0 and reloading == false then
        debounce = true
        shotgunAmmo -= 1
        tool.Shoot:FireServer(mouse.Hit.Position)
        muzzleFlash.Enabled = true
        muzzleLight.Enabled = true
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..shotgunAmmo.."/"..maxshotgunAmmo..""
        print(shotgunAmmo)
        task.wait()
        shotgunShootAnimTrack:play()
        task.wait(0.1)
        muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
        muzzleLight.Enabled = false
        task.wait(0.4)
        tool.Sounds["Shotgun Debounce"]:play()
        task.wait(0.6)
        debounce = false
    elseif shotgunAmmo <= 0 and reloading == false then
        reload()
    end
end)

-- User Input Reload
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(inputObject, isTyping)
    if isTyping then return end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R and shotgunAmmo < maxshotgunAmmo then
        reload()
    end
end)

-- Equip Function
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Equip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = true
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..shotgunAmmo.."/"..maxshotgunAmmo..""
    print("equipped!")
    reloading = false
    muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
    muzzleLight.Enabled = false
end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Unequip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = false
    reloading = true
    muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
    muzzleLight.Enabled = false
end)

**-- This is my "minigunLocalScript" that controls my minigun tool**

local userInputService = game:getService("UserInputService")
local runService = game:GetService(("RunService"))
local debris = game:GetService("Debris")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local tool = script.Parent
local debounce = false
local playerDead = false
local equipCheck = false
local smgShootAnim = tool.Animations:WaitForChild("smgShootAnim")
local smgShootAnimTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(smgShootAnim)
local muzzleFlash = tool.Handle.Barrel.ParticleEmitter
local muzzleLight = tool.Handle.Barrel.PointLight
muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
muzzleLight.Enabled = false
tool.Handle.Magazine.Transparency = 0

local smgAmmo = 24
local maxsmgAmmo = 24
local reloading = false

local holding = false
local lastShot = 0
local shotDelay = 0.05

humanoid.Died:Connect(function()
    playerDead = true
    tool:Destroy()
end)

-- Reload Function
local function reload()
    if reloading == false then
        reloading = true
        local fakeMag = tool.Handle.Magazine:clone()
        fakeMag.Parent = game.Workspace
        tool.Handle.Magazine.Transparency = 1
        fakeMag.WeldConstraint:Destroy()
        fakeMag.CanCollide = true
        debris:AddItem(fakeMag, 5)
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = "Wait..."
        tool.Sounds["SMG Reload"]:play()
        task.wait(3)
        tool.Handle.Magazine.Transparency = 0
        smgAmmo = maxsmgAmmo
        player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..smgAmmo.."/"..maxsmgAmmo..""
        reloading = false
    end
end

-- Shooting Function
local function shoot()
    local time = tick()
    if time - lastShot >= shotDelay then
        lastShot = time
        if playerDead ~= true and debounce == false and smgAmmo > 0 and reloading == false then
            debounce = true
            smgAmmo -= 1
            tool.Shoot:FireServer(mouse.Hit.Position)
            muzzleFlash.Enabled = true
            muzzleLight.Enabled = true
            smgShootAnimTrack:Play()
            player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..smgAmmo.."/"..maxsmgAmmo..""
            print(smgAmmo)
            task.wait(0.05)
            muzzleFlash.Enabled = false
            muzzleLight.Enabled = false
            debounce = false
        elseif smgAmmo <= 0 and reloading == false then
            reload()
        end
    end
end

tool.Activated:Connect(shoot)

-- User Input Reload
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(inputObject, isTyping)
    if isTyping then return end
    if inputObject.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R and smgAmmo < maxsmgAmmo then
        reload()
    elseif inputObject.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and equipCheck == true then
        holding = true
        print(holding)
    end
end)

userInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if gameProcessedEvent then return end
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        holding = false
        print(holding)
    end
end)

runService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if holding == true then
        shoot()
        print(holding)
    end
end)

-- Equip Function
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Equip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = true
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Text = ""..smgAmmo.."/"..maxsmgAmmo..""
    print("equipped!")
    reloading = false
    equipCheck = true
end)

tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    tool.Sounds["Gun Unequip"]:play()
    player.PlayerGui["Health+AmmoGUI"].TotalHPBar.ammoAmount.Visible = false
    reloading = true
    holding = false
    equipCheck = false
end)
```

